# how to convert the CT scan image into 3D model using c++( vtk )?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, vtk

I am working on a project, in this project I want to convert the CT Scan images into 3d model. I am using visual c++ and vtk .I don't have a lot of knowledge about this project. Please anyone help me how it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated project and the question is too abstract. Do you need visualization or only conversion?

For visualization, you may have a look at this examples:

https://visualizationlibrary.org/docs/2.0/html/pag_guide_raycast_volume.html
https://visualizationlibrary.org/docs/2.0/html/pag_guide_sliced_volume.html

They are not from VTK but from Visualization Library(VL). It is not as huge and complex as VTK, so may be it will give you the better idea of rendering principles used for CT visualization.

For conversion from volume to surface, there is a marching cube technique:
https://visualizationlibrary.org/docs/2.0/html/pag_guide_marching_cubes.html